# Adding a upper level index to a MultiIndex pandas df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a df:

```
   VLA 
0   40 
1  200
```

and then a multi-index that looks like this:

```
                stuff1                         ...  stuff2                    
                   p1            p1       p2  ...       p3       p4       p4
dates                                          ...                              
2019-12-01  596.973988  1268.966237  0.969522  ...  2.344248  1.365735  2.903094
2019-12-02    1.100081     2.338402  1.249667  ...  2.815914  1.387209  2.948740
```

How would I create a dataframe that takes `VLA` as an upper index on the second dataframe so it would look like this:

```
VLA                             40            ...              200
                stuff1                         ...  stuff2                    
                   p1            p1       p2  ...       p3       p4       p4
dates                                          ...                              
2019-12-01       596            1268 0.969522  ...  2.344248  1.365735  2.903094
2019-12-02    1.100081     2.338402  1.249667  ...  2.815914  1.387209  2.948740
```

`print (df.columns.levels[0])`

```
Index(['stuff1', 'stuff2', 'stuff3', 'stuff4', 'stuff5', 'stuff6', 'stuff7'], dtype='object')
```

`print (lvl0.map(d)`

```
Float64Index([ 43.0,  43.0,  43.0,  43.0,  43.0,  43.0,  43.0,  43.0, 210.0,
              210.0, 210.0, 210.0, 210.0, 210.0, 210.0, 210.0,   nan,   nan,
                nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
                nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
                nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
                nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,   nan,
                nan,   nan],
             dtype='float64')
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.levels[0])` ?

Comment: @jezrael : `Index(['stuff1', 'stuff2', 'stuff3', 'stuff4', 'stuff5', 'stuff6', 'stuff7'], dtype='object')` - its worth noting that all these are on a VLA specific level, i.e: if there is 2 entries in VLA then there are 2 lots of stuff1-7

Comment: ok, it was mentioned my question

Comment: @jezrael - Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('hh1', '43'),
('hh2', '43'),
('hh3', '43'),
('hh4', '43'),
('hh1', '210'),
('hh2', '210'),
('hh3', '210'),
('hh4', '210')],
)
final2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=mux)

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([final2.columns.get_level_values(0).unique(), ['43', '210']])
print (mux)
MultiIndex([('hh1',  '43'),
            ('hh1', '210'),
            ('hh2',  '43'),
            ('hh2', '210'),
            ('hh3',  '43'),
            ('hh3', '210'),
            ('hh4',  '43'),
            ('hh4', '210')],
           )
```

Comment: Oo wow this is cool. Only issue is, `43` pulls through, but `NaN` appears for the second index

Comment: @Bob - Do you think instead `200` ?